# Type of lighting used in Mario & Sonic 2016 renders

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

[image][image][image]

Hello there! I was wondering if anyone could help
me figure out what type of lighting is being used
In these renders from M&S 2016 and If there's a way to set it up in Blender Cycles?

EDIT: Since I can't add comments because of a "50 reputation" rule, I'll explain what I'm trying to achieve: For those asking what I've tried so far, I've tried using 2 sun lamps along with a cube on top of a model to achieve that same rim light effect around the character in cycles. So basically, what I'm trying to achieve is a similiar rim light effect used around these renders.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this doesn't seem to be about Blender

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos really? This is perfectly doable in blender, we just don't know what the OP has tried that didn't work.

Comment: It totally is, as much as it is doable in any other software, just doesn't seem to be a technical question nor about Blender itself. Sounds maybe more like a "copy this art style" at best

Comment: Could you clarify what about the lighting you are looking to reproduce? (the rim light? the shadows?)